# Facebook APP, Rate Limit Reached, Invalid method call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got next error in my Facebook APP. I want to know how I can investigate "Invalid method call 1471%".

I can't look at the code or proxy all traffic from my app to facebook ((( but I should catch and stab this error. How I can contact technical facebook support.

[image: Rate Limit Reached, Invalid method call]

Comment: you need to find out when that happens and for what api call exactly. implement some logging in your app.

Comment: Make logging it's ideal situation, but I can not make changes in the code base. I can only write rules for iptables and disable same traffic.

Comment: if it´s not your app, then you should talk to the people who can change the code base and include some logging. or maybe log traffic to graph.facebook.com?

Comment: @luschn _"or maybe log traffic to graph.facebook.com?"_ - don't think that would/should be possible, without compromising the HTTPS connection ...

Comment: Not sure if the error-related app insights metrics (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights/) give any more details about the actual calls. Noticing on your screenshot how it says `GET {invalid-id-id}/videos` though, maybe that's a point to start looking into.

Comment: @luschn  can this error "Invalid method call 1 459%" be from request which uses access_token which was expired (error: 190, sub_error: 460)?